# Is the place for the king/queen's feet on a throne called the 'threshold' of the throne?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Is the place for the king/queen's feet on a throne called the 'threshold' of the throne?

The place for the feet can be seen in this picture:

[image: The threshold of the throne]

Comment: I've not heard that usage anywhere, neither is it mentioned anywhere on Oxford or Merriam-Webster. What made you ask so?

Comment: That folding shelf would normally be referred to simply as a footrest.

Answer (score 1):

Might it simply be a "footrest?"

OED

foot-rest   n. a bench, stool, or the like, used for supporting a person's feet.

1861   A. Beresford-Hope Eng. Cathedral of 19th Cent. 148   Only three of the ranges were really sittings, the remainder having served as steps and footrests.

Answer (score 1):

The word "threshold" means the bottom of a door frame. It is the point you cross to pass through a door. Because of this it is commonly used figuratively to mean the point entering into something else, with a very strong connotation of a transition from one state to another.

For example, a college student's graduation might be the threshold to his adult life, meaning it is the point where he enters into his adult life, transforming from sophomoric student to responsible adult. One particularly notable example of this is the tradition of a groom carrying his bride across the threshold (literally picking her up and carrying her through the doorway.) This is symbolic of them transitioning from single life and entering into their new married life together.

I have never heard threshold used with respect to a throne. I think perhaps you misheard or misunderstood. The item in question would be called a footrest. However, it is possible that in some context people would talk about crossing the threshold of court, meaning entering into the presence of the monarch, and consequently transitioning from the being outside the orbit of the King, to being within his orbit. Perhaps in some rare cases their might have been some sort of symbolic line or such that would represent that transition, though that is simply speculative. It is certainly not common terminology.

Answer (score -1):

the word threshold doesn't have the meaning what OP says .. Refer this : http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/threshold

You can refer to the link I gave, no where it is mentioned that threshold means place of king's or queen's feet...